# Wikidata API Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mediawiki-api, wikidata

When querying wikidata, I get a Access-Control-Allow-Origin error.

My request is sent using Axios from a Reactjs web app:

```
let query = "https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetentities&format=json&titles=La_Cha%C3%AEne_Info&sites=enwiki|frwiki";
axios.get(query, (response) => {
    ...
});
```

Adding `origin=*` as for the wikipedia api does not work and replacing `www` by `en` returns an insecure response.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: Use a proxy, either on your server or third party service

Comment: Don't know why axios isn't working. `fetch` will work when adding `origin=*`. Demo here: https://codesandbox.io/s/kwxo1k4p0r